# Removing inner CV joint from differential

Tags: toyota, differential, cv-joint, tacoma

This is a 2007 Toyota Tacoma.

[image]

I removed the outer CV joint from the rotor but am unable to pull the inner one out of the differential. I tried three different pry bars unsuccessfully. Do I need a special tool or am I using a wrong pry bar, or using it wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inner joint can be a PITB, but you are going about it the right way. Here's an image of what it looks like in the splined side of the inner:

[image]

On the end of it, there's the small ring. It is what holds the axle securely in place. To get it out, is just a matter of applying the right amount of pressure in the right direction. The ring has to compress, and the axle comes out. I can tell you don't be afraid to apply some force, because it will take some. A prybar is usually your best bet. You just need to find the leverage point between the two parts (like wedging it off of one of the protruding bolts) so as to get the ring collapsed.

Comment: pry bars come in a million different shapes and angles. do you know which would be best?

Comment: @amphibient - Realistically, it comes down to whatever works. Whatever works is usually what will fit where you need to get it into. IF you have something [like this](https://www.amazon.com/SN-KNIFE-Teardrop-Puller-High-Carbon-Steel/dp/B09QX1GQ24), it might work out well for you. With the 90° claw, it can get in behind the end of the joint and will go right along side the shaft. Putting the end down onto one of the bolt heads, then prying it outwards. Finding the space to make this stuff happen is where the problems lie.

Comment: i tried one just like that but didn't do it -- maybe I didn't apply enough force

Comment: @amphibient - Instead of prying directly away from the axle, try going 90° from that so you are using a lot more leverage ... I really hope that makes sense.

Comment: do you think I will have to replace the ring at the end?

Comment: @amphibient - Nope. It should be just fine. It is designed to compress and pop out of there and be reused. Should not be an issue.

Comment: hey, one more question -- what do you call the ribbed mechanical pattern at the very ends of the CV axle where there is something like 30 ridges and valleys?

Comment: @amphibient - Those are "splines".

Answer (score 1):

These are usually held in by a split ring that goes into a socket and the ring expands and retains the shaft.

Yes, they can be difficult to remove.  I've found that it often takes a quick/sharp shove to get the ring to snap out.  Be sure you are resting the pivot of the pry bar on something solid like one of the bolt heads and not the housing.

[image: CV Shaft Retention Clip]

Comment: Wouldn't a slide hammer be idea for this?

Comment: pry bars come in a million different shapes and angles. do you know which would be best?

Comment: I've never used anything but a pry bar but it's possible a slide-hammer might be effective.

Answer (score 1):

Short, sharp shock will remove it. But you need to do it in two opposing places. Get ready to be showered in fluid if you can't drain first. That's happened a few times to me!