# CV axle won't lodge into differential

Tags: differential, cv-joint

I am struggling to lodge my CV axle into the differential. I was just trying to push it in without the use of any tools but it seems like it won't penetrate all the way, with about an inch gap. Is this normal and do I need to keep pushing? I did struggle to get them out. Could it be that the ring is damaged and need to be replaced?

[image]

[image]

**RELATED:** [Removing inner CV joint from differential](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/89340/removing-inner-cv-joint-from-differential)

Comment: When you create a new question, would you please ensure the year/make/model of the vehicle in question is in the question?

Comment: @Paulster2 -- I think this is less vehicle specific and more general, ie could apply to any

Comment: but i think i am learning that the snap ring is not reusable so maybe that's it

Comment: Can you add a photo of the splined end of the shaft you are having trouble with?

Comment: On some of these it takes a considerable amount of force to compress the snap-ring and seat the CV shaft into place.  In some cases tools will be required.  But check for damage at the end and inside the transmission opening for any obstructions first.

Comment: @HandyHowie -- good point, will do later

Comment: @HandyHowie -- done

Comment: Clean that end and especially the grooves with some brake cleaning spray so that it's clear if there is gunk lodged behind the ring.  Then post another couple of photos.  The first photo especially, looks to be very dirty.  You don't want to put that back into your transmission anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a curved tip 36" prybar to a notch in the CV cup (see picture) and hammered it with a 3 lb sledge hammer and that did it.

[image]